# Add two numbers in a form without button using JavaScript (in cshtml MVC)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am building in .net-mvc and I will like to substract two numbers in a textbox and display in another textbox all in the View (cshtml). I have tried all ways but can't figure out why it will not work.

```js
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("sale").value);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("cost").value);
var c;

a.onkeyup = function() {
  var c;
  if (isNaN(a.value) == false) {
    c = (parseInt(a.value) || 0) - (parseInt(b.value) || 0);
    document.getElementById("profit").value = c;
  }

}
b.onkeyup = function() {

  if (isNaN(b.value) == false) {
    c = (parseInt(a.value) || 0) - (parseInt(b.value) || 0);
    document.getElementById("profit").value = c;

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-5">
  <form method="get" action="InsertBattCalcDetails">
    <fieldset>
      <legend><span class="number">1</span> Insert Battery Calculations</legend>

      Date: <input type="date" name="Date" /> <br /> Battery Value: <input type="number" name="Batt_value" /> <br /> Battery Sales: <input type="text" name="Batt_sales" id="sale" /> <br /> Battery Cost: <input type="text" name="Batt_cost" id="cost" />      <br /> Battery Profit: <input type="text" name="Batt_profit" id="profit" /> <br /> Battery Bought: <input type="number" name="Batt_bought" /> <br />

    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `a` supposed to be? You initialise it as `parseInt(document.getElementById("sale").value);` which means it will be a number but then use use it as if it's an element by calling `a.onkeyup` and `a.value`. Same with `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `a` and `b` should hold references to elements with ids sale and cost respectively. As you have defined them, they are just number values, on which it does not make any sense on registering events, like onkeyup.

By changing `a` to `saleInput` and `b` to `costInput` would make your code more readable:

```js
var saleElement = document.getElementById("sale");
var costElement = document.getElementById("cost");

saleElement.onkeyup = calculateProfit;
 
costElement.onkeyup = calculateProfit;

function calculateProfit() {
  let sale = parseInt(saleElement.value, 10);
  let cost = parseInt(costElement.value, 10);
  
  if(isNaN(sale) || isNaN(cost)) {
      // either sale or cost are not numbers. profit cannot be calculated.
      return;
  }
  
  let profitElement = document.getElementById("profit");
  profitElement.value = sale - cost;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-5">
<form method="get" action="InsertBattCalcDetails">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><span class="number">1</span> Insert Battery Calculations</legend>

        Date: <input type="date" name="Date" /> <br />
        Battery Value: <input type="number" name="Batt_value"  /> <br />
        Battery Sales: <input type="text" name="Batt_sales" id="sale" /> <br />
        Battery Cost: <input type="text" name="Batt_cost" id="cost" /> <br />
        Battery Profit: <input type="text" name="Batt_profit" id="profit" /> <br />
        Battery Bought: <input type="number" name="Batt_bought" /> <br />

    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that am developing in asp.net-mvc. The View format is cshtml (I updated the question). I added <script><script/> to the JavaScript code and it still doesn't work.  Please any other recommendation? Thanks

Comment: Got it work. I added  **AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"**  to the html code. Thank you for your help

Comment: @NAHEEMOLANIYAN You are welcome. I am glad that I helped. However, I missed something in your explanation. `AutoPostBack` is a property of ASP.NET controls that are used in ASP.NET WebForms, not in ASP.NET MVC. You have mentioned that you are developing in ASP.NET MVC. So I can't get it how you used this. Let alone the fact that in your HTML code I don't see any ASP.NET control.

Answer (score 1):

**Try**

```html
<div class="form-style-5">
        <form method="get" action="InsertBattCalcDetails">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><span class="number">1</span> Insert Battery Calculations</legend>

                Date: <input type="date" name="Date" /> <br />
                Battery Value: <input type="number" name="Batt_value" /> <br />
                Battery Sales: <input type="number" name="Batt_sales" id="sale" onkeyup="substract()"/> <br />
                Battery Cost: <input type="number" name="Batt_cost" id="cost" onkeyup="substract()"/> <br />
                Battery Profit: <input type="text" name="Batt_profit" id="profit" /> <br />
                Battery Bought: <input type="number" name="Batt_bought" /> <br />

            </fieldset>

            <script>
                function substract() {
                    var sale = document.getElementById("sale").value;
                    var cost = document.getElementById("cost").value;

                    if (sale && cost) {
                        document.getElementById("profit").value = sale - cost;
                    }

                }  
            </script>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Working now, but just added **AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server"** to the html code. Thank you for your help